# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid IPv4 format J2me Midp 2.0 and Asp.net version 4.0

Tags: asp.net, java-me, ksoap2, midp

I have to access IIS Asp.net version 4.0 services through j2me Application, MIDP-2.0. Same J2me code can able to access Asp.net version 2.0 services.

I am not able to figure out what and where I have to make changes in my J2me code? Googled a lot for this but didn't get any solution. My code is as follow:

```
    public String loginVerification(String userId, String pwd){
        String Method_Name = "mLogin";
        //String Method_Name = "LoginCheck";
        try{
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE_URL, Method_Name);
        request.addProperty("userid", userId);
        request.addProperty("password", pwd);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransport ht = new HttpTransport(Constants.LOGIN_URL);
        ht.debug = true;
        ht.call(Constants.NAMESPACE_URL+Method_Name, envelope); // getting error here
        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        return result.toString();
        }catch(IOException e){
            return e.getMessage().toString();
        }catch(XmlPullParserException e){
            return e.getMessage().toString();
        }

    }
```

I'm using Ksoap2-j2me-core 2.12 jar to access the Asp services.

Comment: I seriously need your help guys. Give me some clues only, I'll handle rest of the part.

Comment: [WebMethod]
    public string mLogin(string userid, string password)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        CommonDataEntity cd = new CommonDataEntity();
         sqlfilter filter = new sqlfilter();
        int retVal=cd.Select_CustomerLogin(filter.SqFilter(userid), filter.SqFilter(password), out message);

        if (retVal > 0 && message == "User")
        {

            
            return "true#"+cd.mLogin(userid);

        }
        else
        {
            return "false#"+userid;
        }
        
    
    }

Comment: Above is my web Method...

Comment: gnat Sir could you tell me what's the prob in above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made changes in URL and I got my issue solved. 
Url was like "http://anup.abc.com/mService/someService.asmx"

replaced the same with "http://121.211.23.123/mService/someService.asmx" and got the output.